# Problems using webpack externals with react-jsx

Tags: reactjs, webpack, external

I'm trying to use react v17 with webpack externals, but got something wrong:

```
react-jsx-runtime.production.min.js:9 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'ReactCurrentOwner' of undefined
    at Object../node_modules/react/cjs/react-jsx-runtime.production.min.js (react-jsx-runtime.production.min.js:9)
    at l (bootstrap:19)
    at Object../node_modules/react/jsx-runtime.js (jsx-runtime.js:4)
    at l (bootstrap:19)
    at load script:2
    at Function.l.a (async module:58)
    at Object../src/index.tsx (load script:2)
    at l (bootstrap:19)
    at startup:4
    at startup:4
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hIwq.png)

my configs:

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "types": ["webpack-env"],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "lib": [
      "DOM",
      "DOM.Iterable",
      "ESNext"
    ]
  }
}
```

```
// webpack.config.js
{
  externalsType: 'script',
  externals: {
    react: ['https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js', 'React'],
    'react-dom': ['https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js', 'ReactDOM'],
  },
}
```

the problem may caused by tsconfig.compilerOptions.jsx = 'react-jsx', but how to solve the problem by just using with the 'react-jsx' config?

Answer (score 0):

The name of "at Object../node_modules/react/cjs/react-jsx-runtime.production.min.js (react-jsx-runtime.production.min.js:9)" is "cjs".
If you want to import it by cdn, you should use umd.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).